# The root filesystem on /dev/sda3 requires a manual fsck

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

When I turn on my computer, it sends me directly to the GRUB menu. When I select Ubuntu, it sends me to a black screen. When I select Advanced Options, it sends me to a series of commands where I get an error:

[image]

```
/ dev / sda3: Unexpected Inconsistency; RUN fsck MANUALLY
(i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited status code 4
The root filesystem on / dev / sda3 requires a manual fsck
BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1: 1.27.2-2ubntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

Comment: I see a number of I/O errors, so I would stop trying to use your drive, boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) and I would firstly view the SMART details for your drive (`smartctl` or `gnome-disks` to see if it's *dying*; if so do not fix; just get any data off it you need in it's remaining life), or is it just a few sectors & can be fixed, then `fsck`, `badblocks` etc.   Investigate the I/O errors first to learn the why, before you consider fixing the errors or make other plans.